# Using a loop to create multiple dataframes from a single dataset

Tags: r

Quick question for you. I have the following:

```
a <- c(1,5,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,3)
b <- c("a","a","f","d","f","c","a","r","a","c")
c <- c(.2,.6,.4,.545,.98,.312,.112,.4,.9,.5)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

What i am looking to do is utilize a for loop to create multiple data frames from rows based on the column contents of column B (i.e. a df for the "a," the "d," and so on).

At the same time, I would also like to name the data frame based on the corresponding value from column B (df will be named "a" for the data frame created from the "a."

I tried making it work based off the answers provided here [Using a loop to create multiple data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832171/using-a-loop-to-create-multiple-data-frames-in-r) but i had no luck.

If it helps, I have variables created with levels() and nlevels() to use in the loop to keep it scalable based on how my data changes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `list2env(split(df, df$b), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: It's often better to *not* split your data like this, but instead use tools like `dplyr`'s `group_by` when you want to do separate calculations for each `b` group.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
require(dplyr)

df$b <- as.character(df$b)

col.filters <- unique(df$b) 

lapply(seq_along(col.filters), function(x) {
  filter(df, b == col.filters[x])
  }
  ) -> list

names(list) <- col.filters

list2env(list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Naturally, you don't need `dplyr` to do this. You can just use base syntax:

```
df$b <- as.character(df$b)

col.filters <- unique(df$b) 

lapply(seq_along(col.filters), function(x) {
  df[df[, "b"] == col.filters[x], ]
  }
  ) -> list

names(list) <- col.filters

list2env(list, .GlobalEnv)
```

But I find `dplyr`much more intuitive.

Cheers

Comment: @d.b 's example is much more elegant IMO.

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the two ways to go about it; i had never thought about using dplyr :|