# How to export a list of dataframes generated as output within R to a single excel sheet

Tags: html, r, excel, dataframe

below is a reproducible sample dataframe generated in R. The number of colums is the same for each investor(given by ID). What is different is the number of rows. I would like to export this multiple list of data frames(for each investor) into a single excel sheet. There are over 3000 investors(with differeing number of rows). Please help out

```
 [[993]]   
   investor asset quantity    price   datetime    RG_count  RL_count  PG_count  PL_count
1    1011     MC   2200          8     2016-03-02        0        0        0        0
2    1011     NIJL  100          50     2016-02-22       NA       NA       NA       NA
3    1011     RPAL   300          2     2016-02-16        0        0        0        0
[[994]]
  investor  asset  quantity    price    datetime            RG_count RL_count PG_count PL_count
1    1156   LOYV   1400        10.54   2010-09-15 01:00:00        0        0        1        0

[[995]]
  investor asset quantity   price            datetime RG_count RL_count PG_count PL_count
1    1140   LPC    13272 551.302 2017-03-27 01:00:00        0        0        1        0

[[996]]
  investor asset quantity    price      datetime             RG_count RL_count PG_count PL_count
1    1941   MBK    2700     62.20     2017-04-24 01:00:00        0        0        0        3

[[997]]
  investor asset quantity price   datetime              RG_count RL_count PG_count PL_count
1    1944   JFM   -79040  17.00   2011-07-14 01:00:00        0        0        1        0
2    1944   MC  -221490  3.00     2010-10-20 01:00:00        0        0        1        0
3    1944  RAPL   -59340  1.20    2012-03-13 00:00:00        0        0        0        0
4    1944   XT   -56300  1.75     2012-03-22 00:00:00       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: You could start by reading up on the excellent `openxlsx` package. Then you can add sheets and content procedurally. Not sure how usable an excel with 3000 sheets will be thou

Comment: You could use `bind_rows()` from the `dplyr` package to create a single data frame and then output that to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, I recommend using `bind_rows()` from the `dplyr` package to append your data frames, and `write.xlsx` from the `openxlsx` package to create your new file.

```
install.packages("dplyr", "openxlsx")
library("dplyr", "openxlsx")
```

If all of your data exist in a single data frame, good news! Your adventure ends here.

```
example <- bind_rows(investors_dataframe)
write.xlsx(example, "/Users/Username/Documents/filename.xlsx")
```

However, if you are trying to combine [multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832171/using-a-loop-to-create-multiple-data-frames-in-r), a good approach would be to [create a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) of all your data frames, then [use that list as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/combine-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-by-row) for `bind_rows`:

```
example2 <- bind_rows(list_of_dataframes)
write.xlsx(example2, "/Users/Username/Documents/filename.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 most common solutions to bind lists are:

```
# Base R
do.call("rbind", myList)
# dplyr
dplyr::bind_rows(myList)
# data.table
data.table::rbindlist(myList)
```

Benchmark is [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/406521_7fc7b6c1dc374e9b8860e15a699d8bb0.html#:%7E:text=bind_rows()%20is%20half%20as%20fast%20as%20rbindlist()%20.)

The openxlsx or writexl package can be a good choice to write out your data.

Benchmark is [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/09/the-writexl-package-zero-dependency-xlsx-writer-for-r/)